# Problems with navigation from jsp to controller

Tags: java, spring

I can't navigate to my controller from the JSP. What am I missing?
I'm having an error status 404.

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>WELCOME PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>WELCOME TO NUTS </h1>
<br/>
<form action="remember.html">

    <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller -----------------------------------------------

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {



     @RequestMapping(value = "/remember")
      public String list(Model model) {
         ServiceFacade facade = new ServiceFacadeImpl();
         List<Product> products = facade.getAllProducts();
         model.addAttribute("products", products);
         return "/jsp/LoginPage";
     }



}
```

This is the web.xml--------------------------------------------------

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>NutsAboutCandyWebProject</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>
</web-app>
```

This is my servlet-context.xml ----------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

  <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.controller"/>

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_nutsaboutcandy"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.model</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean> -->

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> -->
</beans>
```

EDIT 1:

web.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>NutsAboutCandyWebProject</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

  <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
  <beans:bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">      
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/" />      
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />   
  </beans:bean>

  <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.controller"/>

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_nutsaboutcandy"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.model</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <!--  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>  -->

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <!--  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>  -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as `<form action="remember.html">` vs `@RequestMapping(value = "/remember")` ?

Comment: it doesn't work either

Comment: Could You post Your other files? Configuration, LoginPage etc.

Comment: Show your configurations.

Comment: sorry for the delay guys.

Answer (score 0):

the value you are returning is return "/jsp/LoginPage";
which means, your controller will be saying, "hey i have done my operation and returning you the view page LoginPage" so now, your view resolver's work is to add the appropriate suffix and render it.

Now,
1. have you declared a view resolver in your servlet-context.xml file?
2. had you declared it, you need not have to specify "/jsp/" this you can add as a prefix in your view resolver.

Also, i see that you are sending action = "remember.html" and your controller is looking for "/remember". both are different. meaning, you have to write something like "form action = "/remember" "
This means, /remember is an end point. not a html page.

Comment: Your last paragraph is false if they are using extension mapping for their servlet.

Comment: my LoginPage is placed inside a folder named jsp so that I have to put a prefix.

Comment: when you specify a request mapping, you hit an endpoint right? not a static resource right?

Comment: @Erika Is the JSP in `/jsp/jsp/..`. That's where your `ViewResolver` and controller will look for it currently.

Comment: @Erika you can specify that within your view resolver

Comment: `<beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>`  this is how it looks... an example... you have to add that to your servlet-context.xml

Comment: @Erika your request mapping has no method `@RequestMapping(value = "/remember", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: @Erika once you do the changes, update your code so we can follow through

Comment: i see that the prefix value is not correct it should have been, `/jsp/` and then, your view resolver will be rendering jsp pages and not html pages

Comment: @Erika you have a view resolver that resolves your views to JSP. Your view resolver is actually looking for `/jsp/jsp/LoginPage.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you haven't shown it to us, you haven't mapped your `DispatcherServlet` to handle any requests.

You only have

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

which declares a `Servlet`, but nothing else.

You need a mapping, something like

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I've done this thing a while ago and it results to error 404 at the first run so I removed it..

Comment: @Erika If you remove it (as you currently have), your `DispatcherServlet` **won't handle any requests**. The idea is to do it _correctly_.

Comment: It produces a warning that no mapping was found for HTTP request with URI.........

Comment: @Erika That's progress. Now the `DispatcherServlet` is handling requests, but it doesn't have a `@Controller` handler method to handle the one you sent. What URI is it complaining about?

Comment: my context path is having that warning

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NutsAboutCandyWebProject/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: @Erika What pattern did you use in `url-pattern`?

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @Erika Please read my answer. Mapping to `/*` will handle everything, skipping your `<welcome-file>`. Map it to `/` so that it can be the default `Servlet` or map it to `*.html` for extension mapping, which is what your `form` and `@Controller` handler method are expecting.

Comment: still No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NutsAboutCandyWebProject/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: @Erika Edit your question. Add your new configuration below. Clean and redeploy your application.